# Magento 2 How to Add a New Column to Newsletter Subscribers Grid

Tags: magento2, grid

I've added a new column to the table newsletter_subscriber called "name", now I want to add new grid column with the data from the "name" column.

How can I do it using Event Observers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override grid layout file in your custom module. Create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/newsletter_subscriber_block.xml` and put below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.name" as="name">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscriber Name</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">ccol-name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also you need to override Resource Model for Grid Collection to make name column searchable.
For this create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` and put below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Grid\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Newsletter\Collection" />
</config>
```

and create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Newsletter/Collection.php` and put below code in it.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Newsletter;

class Collection extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Collection
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->showCustomerInfo(true)->addSubscriberTypeField()->showStoreInfo();
        $this->_map['fields']['name'] = 'main_table.name';
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rich Fu :) Welcome

Comment: You've saved my life. Really appreciate your input!

Comment: @SatishDubariya Please tell me how you figure out this much. Really share some knowledge with us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override below file in your theme or module.

vendor\magento\module-newsletter\view\adminhtml\layout\newsletter_subscriber_block.xml

Then you can add new column with the data from field you created in Table