# Add a custom column in the Newsletter Subscribers grid

Tags: magento2

I am starting with Magento 2, I want to add a custom column in the Newsletter Subscribers grid.

So I overload the file: newsletter_subscriber_block.xml.

```
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.SubscribedNewslettersLists" as="SubscribedNewslettersLists">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscribed Newsletters Lists</argument>
                    <argument name="filter" xsi:type="string"></argument>
                    <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Ljr\ListTypesNewsletters\Block\Grid\Renderer\SubscribedNewslettersLists</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

I recover my data well and it's great with DataObject I want to cross data compared to the row.

But I would like to return an array, like for example the store view.
I tried to use the "options" argument instead of "render" but impossible to recover the DataObject.

I noticed that the form for Newsletter Subscribers grid they do not use UI compoment, so I have to proceed with an xml file?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can override grid layout file in using your custom module.Step by step follow [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262226/85907) code.And After code added run following commands like :-

```
remove var/cache folder 
remove var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

After check your admin panel.

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: This answer helps or not ?.