# How to show custom action in Newsletter Subscribers

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configuration, newsletter-subscriber

I am trying to create custom action for newsletter subscribers, however I am unable to see the action as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I have created a file named `newsletter_subscriber_block.xml`, as I suppose this is the file which is going to show the custom action, I found it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262198/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-newsletter-subscribers-grid). However, I also then created a file `newsletter_subscriber_grid.xml`, still I don't see the action in the dropdown menu.

I didn't get any error though, during the module installation.

**UPDATEL: My code in XML file is below.**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <alertaction name="listing_action">
            <action name="email_to_customer">
                <settings>
                    <url path="alert/email/Send"/>
                    <type>email_to_customer</type>
                    <label translate="true">Email</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </alertaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your custom layout newsletter_subscriber_block.xml should look like below:

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.massaction">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="email_to_customer" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">alert/email/send</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

then, your custom massaction will appear. After this, you will need to implement a backend controller and adjust the route in the above snippet

Comment: thanks for the reply, I pasted above code, but it doesn't show, I still have same options as shown in the picture in my question. also how do I mention the `action` and `alertaction` as is in my code, that code works in Sales and Customer page

Comment: Maybe post a link to your module?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/magevision/magento2-mass-email-customers module, and it works for customer & sales, now I am trying to edit it to add newsletter subscriber functionality, I created a new directory `layout` under admin/view, and pasted new file newsletter_subscriber_block.xml with your code. but doesn't show.

Comment: I was able to add it, I had a typo in newslettrer*, instead i had written newsletter. I have a question, Is it necessary for it to be just like this > `<argument name="options" xsi:type="array">` or I can change `name` argument to other e.g. email_to_customer?

Comment: I am getting error however > `LocalizedException): An item needs to be selected. Select and try again.`

Comment: I have updated the answer: name="options" has to remain like this otherwise it would not work when the config gets merged with the core config.. hopefully, this does resolve your first question

Comment: not sure I understand the localisation issue though, it may be out of scope from your inital question?